# ASyncTask - I want to download a file from the internet through a button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, download, android-asynctask

I'm still new to the whole coding thing, but I would like some help with ASyncTask and how to allow it to download my app from the internet straight to my phone through notification or just in the SD Card.

I already have a button inside the activity_main.xml layout which is:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/UpdateButton"
    android:text="@string/Update"
    android:background="#6c0005"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="12dp" />
```

In my MainActivity.Java class I just have right now a button connecting to a string and intent to redirect it to a webview to download it:

```
case R.id.UpdateButton:
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse(getString(R.string.UpdateAV)));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
    break;
```

but instead of that, I would like the file to download straight to the phone or a progress bar saying it is downloading to the External memory or SD Card.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just an example that how you can download a file, you would have to write an equivalent code for this in Android if you want to use `AsyncTask`, in which you will do the same work in the `doInBacground()` method.

```
public class DownloadTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.run();
            try {
                dowanloadFile(new URL("some url"), new File("some file"));
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.start();


   }

private static void dowanloadFile(URL url, File file){
    try {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

this code code uses `commons-io-2.4.jar` library,

you can get little more code her [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242897/android-downloading-multiple-files-with-inputstream-fileoutputstream/34243231#34243231)

you can get path to download at SD card like this

```
final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

with `AsycnTask` it would be like this

```
private class MtDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void ,Void>{

    URL someUrl = new URL("your url String"); //
    File someFile = new File("your file, where you want to save the data");

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, file);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

}
```

make sure you do have internet permission to your app, to do that add this line to your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do I put this in the MainActivity? Or a different java class. Also, where would I put the .jar file? I'm not sure.

Comment: @JRMVN you would have to add the jar file in the **libs** directory of your project

Comment: I have added the code for asycTask you can make that as inner class to the MainActivity or you can have it as a separate class whichever suitable to you.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj! Really appreciate the fast help. I'll let you know how I go on :).

Comment: I've added the first codes into my main activity java class, I've also added the .jar file to the libs folder. Should I add the ASyncTask to the MainActivity.java class too? Also when I do, it highlights 'onPreExecute' and 'onPostExecute' red. Also 'public static void main(String[] args) {'  stays red unless it is changed to this 'public static class DownloadTest {' the start of the code? I'm quite confused here, sorry.

Comment: @JRMVN, the first example was to show how the download method is called in Java, It was written for plain java project for your understanding

Comment: @JRMVN, Once you add a library to the Project by putting the file under **libs** directory you have to add that as library to your project so the Project will use appropriate classes rendered by the library you have added to the project

Comment: @JRMVN, you should check some tutorial for how people are using **AsyncTask**, and then check http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html, you will get the idea what should be done :)